# Unable to Receive Packets over the DPDK interface sent through Packetgen

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, dpdk

I am new to DPDK technology, so try to learn this new thing on my own.
I am running with 2 ubuntu vm i.e. vm-1 & vm-2 hosted on my laptop(windows-10).
I have configured each vm with DPDK enable pci.
Now on vm-1 ,I am running packetgen to send the pcap file towards vm-2.
On vm-2,I am running dpdk testpmd application.
Unfortunately nothing is receiving on vm-2.

I am using Following Setup:

Host Machine: Windows 10 Laptop
Guest VM1 : Ubuntu 18.04
Guest VM2 : Ubuntu 18.04

Guest VM1 Running with pktgen-19.12.0 along with dpdk-stable-19.08.2
Guest VM2 Running With dpdk-stable-19.08.2

This is my 1st question to this forum so please accept my apologies.

Comment: Can you please help me i have tried all configs inside my machines,but i am unbale to communicate between 2 vm on dpdk interface.

Comment: I request you to add the following information for clarity. DPDK NIC type (physical or virtual)? 2. If physical firmware version? 3. are these ports connected by physical cable? 4. Are the interface able to send and receive traffic before bind and run with DPDK? 5. Driver used for DPDK bind?

Comment: @VipinVarghese...I am using virtual NIC on Ubuntu Virtual machines.I am using vfio-pci for dpdk binding.

Comment: i tried with 2 seprate vm with each having dpdk port to communicate with each other as well as having 2 dpdk port on a single vm also...but nothing seems to work

Comment: If possible can we discuss on skype ...because over there i can share live sessions of machine if possible to you....my skype id is harishbec2006 and location is mumbai.

Comment: https://join.skype.com/invite/VpiPZjrSiZ3I   with given link you can join my skype....also FYI...both VM are able to communicate over tcp to each other with virtual interfaces,

Comment: there is couple of information which is not clear, I will reach on skype after 3 hours

Comment: sure...thx for ur support...@VipinVarghese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Harish.malik setup consists of

1. Windows laptop with VMWARE Player.
2. Currently there are 2 instances of the Ubuntu as Guest OS.
3. Each VM has 2 ports of e1000 (emulated) as default devices.

The reason for data traffic getting dropped is because the DPDK port (nic-2) were configured (as default settings). ***Isolating the NIC-2 on each into a separate Virtual Bridge solved the traffic RX-TX issue***. Validated with Pkt-gen on both ends.

[image]

Comment: It was a great help from you..@Vipin Varghese